# Using Sagepay PHP Integration Toolkit

Tags: opayo

When I go to `sagepay/demo/index.php` it gives error:

> Ooops!!!
>   Setup error: curl not loaded.

I follow instructions to install php5 etc but my server is running php7. Is this an issue?

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with your Apache configuration with the curl module not being enabled as this is a required module for the SagePay toolkit.

You should downgrade to PHP 5.6 anyway for SagePay as their toolkit makes use of mcrypt, found in their requirements section (VspPHPKit/demo/readme.html#2) obtained from [here](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/form-integration), which according to http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php is deprecated in PHP 7+.

> The mcrypt extension has been abandonware for nearly a decade now, and was also fairly complex to use. It has therefore been deprecated in favour of OpenSSL, where it will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2.

Comment: This does however leave the opportunity to figure out how to make SagePay and PHP 7+ play nicely as a another issue.

Comment: I got in contact with SagePay over Twitter message and they acknowledge their kits are outdated and have no plans to update them.

Comment: PHP 7.1 + mcrypt seem to be compatible if you want to try that.

Answer (score 0):

"I follow instructions to install php5 etc" - which instructions are these?

You might find the demo code runs better on a server running PHP5, some of the code is pretty ancient and not compatible with php7...